# Bootstrap 5 drodpwn is not sliding down when clicking on submenu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

the rest of the menu not expanding down when i select submenu.submenu selected already but it hides other items,  how i can make it expand to down ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown border-top">
    <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center p-3 link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
      <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="mdo" width="24" height="24" class="rounded-circle">
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end text-small shadow">
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SubMenu</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li>
        <hr class="dropdown-divider">
      </li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think perhaps instead of a `.dropdown` you'll want to use a [`.collapse`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/collapse/) for the submenu, it works well with a [`.list-group`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/list-group/#links-and-buttons).
A `.dropdown` is an overlay (outside the normal document flow), while a `.collapse` (within document flow) has its height animated between `0` and it's normal height.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown border-top">
    <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center p-3 link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
      <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="mdo" width="24" height="24" class="rounded-circle">
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end text-small shadow">
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#submenu">SubMenu</a>
        <div class="collapse list-group" id="submenu">
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 1</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li>
        <hr class="dropdown-divider">
      </li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```